# Laravel Many to many to many sync

Tags: php, laravel, controller, many-to-many

I've got a problem since several days in Laravel.

My database is like attached picture.[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16JyR.png)

User<->Role many-to-many-relationship works correctly.

In addition, I would like to add another many-to-many relationship in role_user pivot table. So I did:

**user.php:**

```
public function roles()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}

public function role_users()
{
   return $this->hasMany(RoleUser::class);
}
```

**role.php:**

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function role_users()
{
   return $this->hasMany(RoleUser::class);
}
```

**And pivot roleUser.php:**

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function role()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}

public function tags()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

When I populate tables, I can get data: relations work.

Now I want to save data and let Laravel to populate tables automatically. At this moment and time, I save roles data in users.php with:

```
$this->Roles()->sync($roles);
```

($roles is an json array data from a form request..).

Pivot table get the *user_id* and *role_id*. Ok, cool.

Now, **what should I write to get *role_user_id* and *tag_id* in role_user pivot table when I add a roles?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried:      $this->role_users()->tags()->sync($someData);    but got error"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::tags()"

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use

```
$this->Roles()->attach($roles);
```

Rather than

```
$this->Roles()->sync($roles);
```

Because if I'm not wrong, sync will remove the pivot data. And you should pass the primary_key and foreign_key to your belongsToMany function. If you wanted to add data to the pivot column in your pivot table, try to add `->withPivot('column name');`

Comment: The probem is not on the first pivot ( role_user table) but the second one ( role_user_tag). For the method attach or sync, no matter because I'm using create/update method in my User controller. Also I simplified a bit the code and I'm using indeed withPivot('xxx') ;)